# How is a LocalJumpError thrown from the following lambda?

Tags: ruby, lambda, ruby-1.9

I've been reading the Ruby Programming Language book by Flanagan-Matz

Context: Difference between Proc.new and lambda w.r.t return statements

The book states that a return within a lambda should **not** raise a LocalJumpError (since lambdas are akin to method calls). A return in a lambda just exits the lambda - not the method enclosing the iterator.

However the following code-snippet says otherwise. What is the catch here?

```
def caller( aProc, switch)
  puts "Start Caller"
  case switch
    when :normal_block; iterator &aProc
    when :block_parameter; iterator_blockparam(&aProc)
    else iterator_param(aProc)
  end
  puts "End Caller"
end

def iterator
  puts "Begin iterator"
  [1,2,3,4].each { |x| yield x  }
  puts "End iterator"
end
def iterator_blockparam(&block)
  puts "Start Iterator wBlockParam"
  puts "Block is {block.lambda? ? 'Lambda' : 'Proc'}"
  [1,2,3,4].each { |x| block[x]  }
  puts "End Iterator wBlockParam"
end
def iterator_param(aProc)
  puts "Start Iterator wParam"
  puts "Block is {aProc.lambda? ? 'Lambda' : 'Proc'}"
  [1,2,3,4].each{ |x| aProc[x]}
  puts "End Iterator wParam"
end
 # enclosing method Proc.new already returned.
no3proc = Proc.new{|x| return -101 if x == 3; puts x }
no3lambda = lambda{|x| return -101 if x == 3; puts x }

#~ caller( no3proc, :normal_block)         #=> LocalJumpError
caller( no3lambda, :normal_block )       #  => LJE
#~ caller( no3proc, :block_parameter)        #=> LJE
#~ caller( no3lambda, :block_parameter)       # works!
#~ caller(no3proc, :with_param)               #=> LJE
#~ caller(no3lambda, :with_param)              # works!
```

Answer (score 4):

<strike>The LJE is not due to returning out of the method, but returning out of the array iterator that calls the block. You can't return from an array iterator. See the behavior reproduced by simply attempting to return from the following each block:</strike>

> > [1,2,3].each {|x| return x }
> >         LocalJumpError: unexpected return
> >             from (irb):7
> >             from (irb):7:in `each'
> >             from (irb):7

EDIT: Ok, I take it back, you CAN return out of an iterator. My LJE was because I was in console (argh).

EDIT: Ok, I see your problem. The basic question is why does `block[x]` work and `yield x` does not (assuming &block is a lambda). <strike>It would seem that `yield x` inlines the interpreted code from block and calls it in the context of the array iterator, which will throw the LJE (as above), and `block[x]` does not inline the code and only returns out of the block itself.</strike>

So, having failed to answer your question, I've at least distilled it down to the following:

```
def call_as_block(&block)
    block.call
end

def call_as_yield
    yield
end

proc_return = Proc.new { return }
lambda_return = lambda { return }

call_as_block &proc_return # throws LJE
call_as_yield &proc_return # throws LJE
call_as_block &lambda_return # does NOT throw LJE
call_as_yield &lambda_return # throws LJE
```

So the difference it would seem is not between lambda and Proc, which behaves as expected, but between calling a lambda through `yield` and calling a lambda through `block.call`. Calling `yield` appears to make the lambda behave as if it were a Proc, and attempts to return out of the context of the method.

Comment: +1 for all the effort :) I spent a Saturday trying to come up with a convincing explanation for this one... before giving up to SO

Comment: Heh, yeah thanks a lot, now I'm obsessed with it as well  :) I'm actually looking at the C code for yield.